Show deleted key pair in aws
I have a launch template with a key pair name, but the name can not be found in cloudtrail. How am I able to retrieve the key pair, because the template is just showing the name and not the key or id of the key pair?
What purpose serves the cloudtrail, if I can neither identify key pair by the id nor find the it via couldtrail?
Why can I not not easily find out, who deleted what? That is a very staightforward requirement in aws and yet almost impossible.

Are you saying that you can see the relevant RunInstances API request logged in CloudTrail but the KeyName is not logged? Also, please add specifics to your question about not being able to find out who deleted what.

If you don't see the DeleteKeyPair event in the CloudTrail Console, it means that (1) you're looking at the wrong account or region, or (2) the deletion happened more than 90 days ago.

@jarmod KeyName is not logged, but the id of the key is. The existing launch template does only how the key name.

Not sure why it logs keypair ID instead of keypair name but presume you can programmatically query the keypair by ID to retrieve the name.
